# Test a PDO query, if it fails, do something else

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch

Greetings fellow Overflowians,

Im working with PHP PDO statments and MySQL. I have a secured admin form that allows the admin to enter in the second half of a MySQL query that is then saved into a database. For example the first part of the query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS count, SUM(`url_count`) AS total 
FROM `table_name` WHERE `tablekey_id` = 1
```

and the user may save the following to the database in the `sql_count` column:

```
AND `row_is_live` = 1 AND `title` > '';
```

So in my program I want to execute the query, however being a user entered it in, the query could fail. So I would like to test to see if the query would fail, and if it would then I would like to do something else so as not to stop my program.

Here's the code I'm working with. I'm currently trying a try catch block but it stops the execution of code.

```
$table = new PatternsGenerator($baseDomain, true);
$sectionRowsQuery = $db->getTopLevelPatternRows($sectionId);
$returnArray = array();
$index = 1;

while ($row = $sectionRowsQuery->fetch()) {
    if(isset($row['sql_count']) && strlen($row['sql_count']) > 0) {
        try {
            $counts = $db->getCountsWithStoredQuery($row['sql_count']);
            throw new Exception("This is an exception");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $counts = array('total' => 1, 'count' => 0);
        }
    } else {
        $counts = array('total' => 0, 'count' => 0);
    }

    $table->getTopLevelRow_1($returnArray, $row['title'], $counts, $row['id'], $index);
    $index++;
}

... more code ....
```

My question is, how can I test a MySQL query to see if it will fail without stopping execution of the rest of the code? Please and thank you all.

---

Edit:

Ok I found the problem. The function getCountsWithStoredQuery($storedQuery) was trying to fetchAll(). So if the query failed it then had fetchAll() executed on it and the program failed. I simply had to move the fetchAll() to the try block to be executed after the query successfully completed.

Thank you everyone who took this question seriously.

Comment: It can if the user is entering part of it. This is defensive programming.

Comment: This is a requirement of the project. I did not choose the project requirement I am programming for someone else. Many projects that exist are not ideal. I'm trying to program this as defensibly as possible to handle errors. In my question I'm asking how something could be done. If you do not know how to do it that's fine but please refrain from snippy comments. Thank you.

Comment: @dianuj Thank you, I'm trying the try catch block but it stops execution. I'm trying to find a way to continue execution if it should hit the catch block.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You should use your omnipotence for good instead of trolling my child.

Comment: Use [Flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_word)

Comment: what do you mean by stops the execution? p.s. this question doesn't deserve a -1.

Comment: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` will make PDO throw exceptions -- you then just need to wrap your query call in a try catch. Still, you should have a sanitiser/regex which checks their input, so a DROP command won't be allowed for example. Using the same sanitiser/regex, you could use that to build valid, safe queries?

Comment: @emma.fn2 Thank you I forgot to set the error mode for this function.

Comment: @itachi Thanks for the not -1 part. I cant help what the customer asks for. And they know how to program so its safe to say they can create their own queries, but lets play it safe. And what I mean is that it hits the catch block because it failed however it doesn't execute any of the ....more code....

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, multi-criteria search and thus conditionally created query is a quite trivial task in web-development.

So, you'd better follow this general way instead of walking dangerous corners, letting users to do whatever SQL injections freely.

It is not much a problem to create a series of conditions, adding query parts based on a users' choice.

but first of all you need to understand that

- **no query have to be intended to fail**
- **no user have to be allowed to inject SQL in your query**

Comment: Its created with a form that lets them pick columns, operators and connecting (AND, OR) statements. Also if you read the question you will notice that its in the Admin part of the program, and is a requirement for a project. Thanks for your answer though it didn't aid me in completing this requirement.

Comment: is this a solution u have not use "Your Common Sense" :)